# Is a deterministic PRNG seeded by with cryptographic hash a secure basis for generating one-time passwords?

Tags: one-time-password

I am building a passwordless auth scheme, and would like to avoid storing temp passwords in memory, so I wanted to derive them rather than store them. A valid password looks something like 'amendable-goofiness-ahead' (a warning which could also be appropriate for this question).

I was thinking we could generate a seed from a combination of a secret salt, username and the current time, then use that to seed a deterministic PRNG (such as PCG64) which is used to select words at random from the EFF 'large word list'.

$$
seed = sha256(username || salt || timestamp)
$$

This password is sent to the user (say, over email), then when the server receives it again, it simply generates all the valid passwords for the past 20 minutes or so and checks the password it received against each of the passwords it generated.

Does this sound like a valid solution? It depends on the salt remaining hidden (this would be stored long term in the database with the rest of the user record), is there a solution that could avoid this?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use webauthn or TOTP? Both are well-used standards.

Comment: I am also planning to support webauthn and TOTP as 2fa, but I'd also like to support 'normal' password based login, as well as passwordless with the email.